# Approximation Algorithm for Maximum-Cut (proving a bound on the optimum)

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, approximation

At the end of section 12.4 in the Local Search chapter from Kleinberg-Tardos's book "Algorithm Design" we are told that we can bound the running time of a proposed Maximum-Cut approximation algorithm via using "big-improvement-flips". The goal here is to use these flips to then place a bound on the running time of our approximation algorithm, but I have yet to understand how to prove statement **(1)** below.

A node flip is a big-improvement-flip if it improves the cut value by at least $\frac{2\epsilon}{n}w(A,B)$ where $n=\vert V \vert$ and $\epsilon > 0$.

We are given 12.6 as a result in the book (12.6 refers to the statement number in the book):

**(1)** Let $(A,B)$ be a partition such that no big-improvement-flip is possible. Let $(A^*,B^*)$ be a globally optimal partition. Then $(2+\epsilon)w(A,B)\geq w(A^*,B^*)$.

The claim is that by simply adding the term $\frac{2\epsilon}{n}w(A,B)$ to each inequality in the original proof, we can prove this. **For original proof see slide 22 at this link, slides preceding slide 22 also describe the proposed approximation algorithm which allows us to find a local optimum by moving from a state $S$ to a state $S^*$ if and only if moving a vertex from one partition to the other increases the value of the cut: [Princeton Kleinberg-Tardos lecture slides](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~wayne/kleinberg-tardos/pearson/12LocalSearch.pdf).**

I had some difficulty simply adding the term and moving through the proof from beginning to end as Kleinberg-Tardos proposed. This has been very frustrating and I just want to prove to myself that that statement **(1)** holds.

My proof attempt:

For any node $u \in A$, we must have

$$\sum_{v\in A} w_{uv} \leq \sum_{v \in B} w_{uv} + \frac{2\epsilon}{n}w(A,B).$$

By summing the inequalities for each pair of vertices with both ends in $A$ and each pair of vertices with one end in $A$ and the other in $B$ we get

$$2 \sum_{\{u,v\}\subseteq A} w_{uv} \leq \sum_{u\in A, v \in B} w_{uv} + 2\epsilon w(A,B) = w(A,B) + 2\epsilon w(A,B).$$

*Note on above step: Since at most $n-1$ vertices are in $A$ we have on the RHS of the inequality $\frac{2\epsilon}{n}w(A,B) \leq (n-1)\frac{2\epsilon}{n}w(A,B) \leq n\frac{2\epsilon}{n}w(A,B) \leq 2\epsilon w(A,B)$

A similar argument follows for any $u \in B$ and hence

$$2 \sum_{\{u,v\}\subseteq B} w_{uv} \leq \sum_{u\in A, v \in B} w_{uv} + 2\epsilon w(A,B) = w(A,B) + 2\epsilon w(A,B).$$

Adding these inequalities gives

$$2 \sum_{\{u,v\}\subseteq A} w_{uv} + 2 \sum_{\{u,v\}\subseteq B} w_{uv} \leq 2w(A,B) + 4\epsilon w(A,B)$$
$$\sum_{\{u,v\}\subseteq A} w_{uv} + \sum_{\{u,v\}\subseteq B} w_{uv} \leq w(A,B) + 2\epsilon w(A,B)$$

At this point I would like to add $w(A,B)$ to both sides and conclude that $W = \sum_e w_e$ is now equal to the LHS (since the LHS now equals the sum total weight of all edges) and then have the RHS be equal to $2w(A,B) + \epsilon w(A,B) \Rightarrow (2+\epsilon)w(A,B) \geq w(A^*, B^*)$, but the bound I am getting is  $2w(A,B) + 2\epsilon w(A,B) \Rightarrow w(A,B)(2+2\epsilon)$.

What am I missing here? I seem to be double counting the term $2\epsilon w(A,B)$.

Comment: The trivial bound, obtained by moving all the vertices in $A^*\Delta A$, yields $w(A^*,B^*)\le w(A,B)+|A^* \Delta A|\frac{2\epsilon}{n}w(A,B)\le w(A,B)+2\epsilon w(A,B) = (1+2\epsilon)w(A,B)$. If $\epsilon > 1$ then the bound stated in your lemma is tighter, while this seems tight already. Given $A,B$, I can choose the weights such that any vertex removed from $A$ will add $\frac{2\epsilon}{n} w(A,B)$ to the weight of the cut.